# Need Advise : Index.js in not able to find the gitlab path of my postman collection while running a job in gitlab CI/CD

Tags: node.js, gitlab, newman, postman-collection-runner

I have uploaded a postman collection, modules, package.json and index.js on GitLab. While executing the index.js using the node index.js command it is failing with the error: can not find module 'PostmanCollection/MPDC.postman_collection.json'. I have provided the GitLab path of the collection in the index.js but still, it ends up failing. This works fine when I am using the local path.

Can anyone please advise me on how to fix this issue?

Here is how my index.js looks:

```
const newman = require('newman');

newman.run({
collection: require('PostmanCollection/MPDC.postman_collection.json'),
reporters: 'cli',
}, function (err){
if (err) {throw err;}
console.log('collection run complete');
});
```

Comment: How does it fail? Are there any error messages? How is gitlab running that script, is there a node environment that gets spun up?

Comment: I did it a slightly different way - https://github.com/DannyDainton/postman-ci-pipeline-example/blob/master/README.md#gitlab

Comment: Hey Danny, Thanks for the information. I did check the project you mentioned and it really helped. I was able to make it work. 

Now I ran into a new issue. So I have written a script in which I am trying to write the response to a file but it seems not working. When I am running the same on my local machine it is working fine.

Comment: Here is how my script looks:
const newman = require('newman');
const fs = require('fs');


newman.run({
    collection: require('C:/Vismay_Docs/Backup/MPDC.postman_collection.json'),
    reporters: 'cli'
}).on('request', function (error, args) {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
    else {
        // Log the response body
        fs.writeFile('C:/Vismay_Docs/Backup/result1.txt', args.response.stream, function (error) {
            if (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        })
    }
});

Comment: @DannyDainton Would you be able to help me with this?

Comment: Either update the original question or close this and create a new one - Please don't try and explain it in the comments.

Comment: Alright! Will do that.